# Information on Planetary nebula formed from the death of our star the 'Sun'!

Tags: the-sun, astrophysics, nebula

I want to know the expansion rate, composition, mass and density of hydrogen present of a Planetary nebula similar to that which will be formed after the death of our star the sun.

Knowing these data is important for me to do some calculations.

Comment: I've trimmed down your question, as your age isn't really relevant.  You could be a bit clearer about what you want these for, as "to do some calculations" is very vague.  I'd also like to know what research you have already done. Also, the values you seek will not be constant over the life of a PN, nor from one part of the nebula to another. However here is a link that may help https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2013/10/aa21532-13.pdf

Comment: @JamesK thanks will keep in mind

Comment: @JamesK thanks for the link

Comment: @JamesK well I am an undergraduate s, just finished 12th grade at school and waiting for results . I have participated at inter school research paper presentations only.

Comment: Yes, my point is that the PN will have exactly the same expansion rate if you were a PhD or a 12 year old!